# C++ :: Calling Member function via pointer before constructor exit

Tags: c++, winapi

I am in a situation where I share pointer to member function to outside during constructor execution. and the member function can be called any time, even before the constructor get completed. I am assuming it could lead to undefined behavior.
this situation arise in following condition.

```
ButtonCtrl::ButtonCtrl(int id, HWND hwnd_parent, int x, int y,
                       int w, int h, const string& text) 
{
    this->hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, L"BUTTON", this->wtext.c_str(),
                        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
                        x, y, w, h, hwnd_parent, (HMENU)id, 
                        GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    this->wndproc_org = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongW(this->hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, 
                                      (LONG) &ButtonCtrl :: wndproc_new);
}
```

Here **wndproc_new** is static class method but consider it none static. Now in **SetWindowLongW** method I replace Button's window procedure with my window procedure (**wndproc_new** ). As button already created using **CreateWindowExW** it's message loop may already started. and Now it can call my **wndproc_new** any time. even before this constructor got finish. So my question is, Do I get undefined behavior or is it valid ?

Comment: You can call member functions before a constructor finishes, provided you don't read uninitialized members in those functions.

Comment: it can not call wndproc_new any time, can not call before constructor got finish. because window procedure (callback) can be called only inside several api calls (`GetMessage`, `PeekMessage`..).

Comment: as side note - need use `SetWindowLongPtrW` and `GWLP_WNDPROC`, and for what you subclass button at all ? why not via `SetWindowSubclass` ?

Comment: *Now it can call my wndproc_new any time.* - this is wrong assumption and you not got UB in any case anyway

Comment: @RbMm I use `SetWindowLongW` because my target is 32 bit. And I want to be specific rather than depend on macro. similarly I did not declare UNICODE instead I use W or A function. _and you not got UB(?) in any case anyway_ ?

Comment: yes, you not got UB in any case here. the `SetWindowLongPtrW` is valid for both 32/64 bit. even if you target **now** only 32 bit - better use *Ptr* version. because will he hard after not use this port code to 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate the answer and all the comment. But I did not find what I am looking for. Probably I fail to explain my question. But the first comment by Evg is the simple and straightforward answer.

> You can call member functions before a constructor finishes, provided
>   you don't read uninitialized members in those functions. – Evg

I search and read some documentation and test, debug some code. I found something which I would like to share here and which may elaborate the answer. The answer may seem off-track but eventually we get on-track.

When the code compiled the member function compiled like other ordinary function. but as we know with special first argument the *this* pointer.

> Can we get pointer to member function without object ?

yes, In the following code we get the pointer to member function without any object (Don't complain about cast, compiler will do). this indicates that member function does not belongs to object (Half True Sentence). But, it is *this* pointer that binds member function to object. it is kind of C struct with function pointer variable where first argument of the function is pointer to C struct itself.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        int test_fun()
        {
            cout << "in test_fun" << endl;
            return 42;
        }
};

typedef int (*INT_FUN_PTR)();
int main()
{
    INT_FUN_PTR test_fun_ptr = (INT_FUN_PTR) &A::test_fun;
    int i = test_fun_ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

But as we cast member function pointer to normal function pointer we get compiler warning. let's ignore it.

> can we call this member function like other normal function using
>   pointer ?

the answer is yes and no. We can but we should never call it like other normal function. As the above code compiled it run normally but if we debug and look at *test_fun* function's stack we can see that the *this* pointer included in stack and it contains garbage value because we did not call *test_fun* using any object notation. we must not use the *this* pointer.

> How the *this* pointer get into stack ?

May be because of function's calling convention (and/or compiler). According to microsoft's documentation, 
[*__thiscall*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=vs-2019) is the calling convention for member function. and the this pointer being passed via register ECX, and not on the stack, on the x86 architecture.

> what if we define *test_fun* with some arguments ?

Following is the redefine version of *test_fun* with *int* argument.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        int test_fun(int i)
        {
            cout << "in test_fun" << endl;
            return i;
        }
};

typedef int (*INT_FUN_PTR)(int);
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int* p = &i;
    INT_FUN_PTR test_fun_ptr = (INT_FUN_PTR) &A::test_fun;
    *p = test_fun_ptr(42);
    //test_fun_ptr(42); // program crash
    return 0;
}
```

Now if we debug this code we can see the stack of the main function after calling *test_fun* get cluttered. if we call it second time program get crash. if we allocate memory and use it after first time calling *test_fun* again program crash.
because of the calling convention and because we call *test_fun* as normal function.

Now lets try to change the calling convention of *test_fun* using [__cdecl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2019)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        int __cdecl test_fun(int i)
        {
            // here stack get cluttered
            cout << "in test_fun" << endl;
            return i;
        }
};

typedef int (__cdecl *INT_FUN_PTR)(int);
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int* p = &i;
    INT_FUN_PTR test_fun_ptr = (INT_FUN_PTR) &A::test_fun;
    *p = test_fun_ptr(42);
    test_fun_ptr(42); // program will not crash
    return 0;
}
```

This time the test_fun function's stack get cluttered. I am surprise, is it possible to use member function as normal function by **specifying** any of calling convention ? but it is not the part of this discussion.

As we can see the member function is just like normal function with special calling convention. it is always there. it bind to object by the *this* pointer. when the object get created, memory allocated (on stack or heap) for members and pointer to memory get push to register. the constructor is the first function which get called. and we can access the *this* pointer via constructor for the first time. if we are able to get the *this* pointer before constructor call (may be via *malloc* which will not call constructor at all), we can call member function even before constructor call. provided not using uninitialized members or even we can initialize members there.

In conclusion, yes it is perfectly normal to call member function before a constructor finishes as many time as you want provided not using uninitialized members.

Answer (score 0):

formal, even from language view, you can call member functions and even virtual functions from constructor body. because virtual table for your class (if it have virtual functions) will be initialized before constructor body. another question - are you initialize all your instance at this point already. i be not call this from constructor, not because this is wrong, UB etc (no), but by style reason.

> Now it can call my wndproc_new any time. even before this constructor got finish

this is wrong. `wndproc_new` is not interrupt. it can not be called at any time. this callback can be called by system only when you call some concrete api like `GetMessage` , `PeekMessageW`, `SendMessage`, `CreateWindowEx`, etc) which can call your window procedure callback. your `wndproc_new` will be called only inside this api call, but not from random place.

also as side note need use `SetWindowLongPtrW` and `GWLP_WNDPROC` even for 32 bit code. and i strong doubt that need change default *WC_BUTTON* window procedure. however if really need subclass it - better use `SetWindowSubclass` or methods like `AtlThunk_*`

---

the general rule - set callback only when you full ready for incoming calls. at any time (despite in concrete case `wndproc_new` can be called only inside several api calls and only from your current thread). anyway after constructor body begin executed - possible call any member functions of class

Comment: *"it can not be called at any time. this callback can be called by system only when you call some concrete api like `GetMessage` and `PeekMessageW`"* -  This is inaccurate. The window procedure *can* be called virtually at any time. `CreateWindow` does, for example. So will any intra-thread call to `SendMessage`. And with `GWLP_WNDPROC` being part of the public interface, all bets are off.

Comment: @IInspectable - not, it can not be called at **any** time. even virtually. only **inside** some system api calls. i not say that **only* inside `GetMessage` and `PeekMessageW`. inside `CreateWindowEx` of course too (and always). inside `SendMessage` too of course

Comment: `CreateWindow` doesn't dispatch incoming sent messages. That makes the statement that *"this callback can be called by system only when you call some concrete api like \[...\] CreateWindowEx \[...\] which Dispatches incoming sent messages"* wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable - sense in that `CreateWindow` can call our window procedure (say we create child window for `this->hwnd` (despite create child for button unusual). *Dispatches incoming sent messages* - in general sense. it simply call window procedure callback

Comment: `CreateWindow/Ex()` directly sends a few messages to the created window, which is before the custom WndProc is set since `RegisterClass/Ex()` is not being used. And `SendMessage()` across thread boundaries does not call the WndProc until the receiving thread calls `(Peek|Get)Message()`. This is all documented behavior.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - i mean if our thread call `SendMessage` to another thread - at this point can window procedure be called. so here visa versa situation. about `CreateWindowEx` - i mean we can create child window for example. and while child window handle self created messages - our window can also receiver some messages (say `WM_PARENTNOTIFY`). so can be different situations really.. but anyway windows procedure not called like interrupt at any time. need direct or indirect call some api for this

Comment: @rem [`SendMessage` dispatches incoming cross-thread messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983).

Comment: @IInspectable while `SendMessage()` is blocking a thread waiting for another thread to reply to a sent message, `SendMessage()` continues to dispatch messages received by the blocked thread. That doesn't really change what I said earlier, that a receiving thread does not dispatch messages until the receiving thread does something that processes messages. Thus a wndproc can't really be called at *any* time, only at *deterministic* times decided by the receiving thread.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - *Thus a wndproc can't really be called at any time, only at deterministic times decided by the receiving thread* - yes, exactly. but call  `SendMessage` for another thread - can consider that our thread decide receive messages, if they exist. inside call `SendMessage` already can be called windowproc. anyway all this weak related to main question - we can call any member functions from constructor body. hidden initialization ( like init vtable) finished before constructor body